# Python classes and inheritance. How to get instances to have main class' argument

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance

Trying to learn Python/programming and I have a question about classes/inheritance. I created a class "Media", and I wanted to create an instance of it called "Movie" to inherit from Media. For Media, I have the publisher hard coded to always equal 'Universal Studios', so I wanted for my Movie to print out Publisher and have it print out 'Universal Studios' but I'm stuck as how to achieve this. I have my code below and tried various syntax but can't figure this out.

```
class Media:
    def __init__(self, publisher = 'Universal Studios', market = 'USA'):
        self.publisher = publisher
        self.market = market

    def get_media_info(self):
        print(self.publisher, self.market)
        return None

class Movie(Media):
    def __init__(self, movie_data):
        super().__init__(movie_data)
        self.movie_data = movie_data

    def test(self):
        print(publisher)

test = Movie(movie_data = {'title': 'one', 'rating': 'two'})
test.test()
```

Comment: `print(self.publisher)`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking about. Currently you're setting `movie_data` as the publisher of your `Movie` instances, since that's the first argument you pass to `super().__init__`. If you don't want to do that, you need to pass something else (perhaps nothing).

Comment: also, you need to ensure that you call the `super().__init__` sensibly. Your base class takes two arguments, but you're only passing `kwargs` from `Movie` which isn't even used in the super.

Comment: Is "Universal Studios" the publisher for *all* `Media` class instances? Or only for all `Movie` instances? If the latter, then you don't want to hardcode that as the default in the base class.

Comment: I want "Universal Studios" to be hard coded for all Media class, and so I'm not sure what exactly needed to be added to the init statement for this. I want the Movie class to have the same publisher/market values as the Media class, but then to also add in the new movie_data argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass no arguments in `super.__init__()`. As mentioned in comments above, the `movie_data` doesn't appear to align with any of the arguments in the base class, so you don't need to send those args to the base class or unexpected results will occur (such as your `self.publisher` returning the `dict` of `movie_data` :)

And then do `print(self.publisher)`, because `publisher` is a property of the class instance, you need to qualify it with the `self`.

```
class Media:
    def __init__(self, publisher = 'Universal Studios', market = 'USA'):
        self.publisher = publisher
        self.market = market
    def get_media_info(self):
        print(self.publisher, self.market)
        return None

class Movie(Media):
    def __init__(self, movie_data):
        super().__init__()
        self.movie_data = movie_data
    def test(self):
        print(self.publisher)

m = Movie(movie_data = {'title': 'one', 'rating': 'two'})
m.test()
```

[image]